# Use re (regular expression) to parse only chunks of a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My laboratory is working with a software that generates a mess of data as output, so I’m trying to make things easier using Python. So far, I believe that the best approach is to generate lists and treat it as chunks of data, but that is not so easy:
The first chunk of data is easy: the 3 columns are fixed and can be obtained simply with:

```
chunk1 = my_data[:3]
```

The 2nd chunk of data is not easy because it can have **2, 3 or 4 columns**. I believe that the key here is that *the 2nd chunk ends when we find a letter* (something like **1    3    7**   *CCC*). In this case I believe that it is possible to use the **re module** to parse the two, three or four columns and stop before the first letter, but I don’t know how to do it. I intend to “normalize” these columns by filling the vacant spots with zeros or “-”, so if I have the 2 columns case I’ll fill it to **[x,  y,  0,  0]** and the 3 columns case with **[x,  y,  z,  0]**.

The 3rd chunk is fixed (two, three or four letters and a number) like this: **CCC   119.62**

And the 4th chunk is the rest.

Here is a representation of the messy output:
[image]

The final result could be something like:
["s 91", "1.00", "OUT"] ["9", "3", "12", "7"] ["OCCC", "0.34"] ["f829", "27","f752","33"]

So far, I’m stuck trying to figure out how to make the **re module** work like this:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated, guys.

**Data sample**

```
s 27    1.00   STRE   30   16   OC    1.355049  f1291 50
s 28   -1.00   STRE    8    6   CC    1.494281  f1340 12  f1271 17
s 29   -1.00   STRE   14   15   NC    1.421282  f1358 49
s 30    1.00   STRE   14   15   NC    1.421282  f1337 10  f1290 33
s 31    1.00   STRE    8    6   CC    1.494281  f1171 15  f323 11
s 32    1.00   STRE   30   31   OC    1.419982  f1082 51  f1077 24
s 33    1.00   STRE   13   11   ClC    1.740581  f842 15  f323 19
s 34   -1.00   BEND    1    3    7   CCC   119.62  f1037 26  f485 10
s 35   -1.00   BEND    3    1    4   CCC   119.74  f1124 29
s 36    1.00   BEND    7    3    1   CCC   119.62  f733 25  f288 13
s 37    1.00   BEND   21   14   15   HNC   116.16  f1578 40  f1560 20
s 38    1.00   BEND   24    5    2   HCC   119.73  f1186 67
s 39    1.00   BEND   25    2    6   HCC   118.80  f1536 53  f1082 10  f1077 17
s 40   -1.00   BEND   24    5    2   HCC   119.73  f1508 44  f1171 14  f1124 13
s 41    1.00   BEND   25    2    6   HCC   118.80  f1669 14  f1271 32  f1124 15
s 42   -1.00   BEND   26   19   18   HCC   119.04  f1578 10  f1560 37  f1291 11
s 89    1.00   TORS   31   30   16   19   COCC     0.24  f161 14  f104 46  f87 19  f43 10
s 90    1.00   OUT     8    2    3    6   CCCC     1.09  f466 36  f125 22
s 91    1.00   OUT     9    3   12    7   OCCC     0.34  f829 27  f752 33
```

Comment: First mistake is the knee-jerk reaction to think of regular expressions. Just read a line, split it into its parts and then process it further according to its content. Of course you can use regular expressions and they might even help validating the lines, but using them should not be a goal in and of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a generator that pulls from an iterator until an alpha string is found.

```
from itertools import chain

def while_not_alpha(iterator):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    for s in iterator:
        if not str(s).isalpha():
            yield s
        else:
            yield chain([s], iterator)
            break

def parse(line):
    *chunk1, rest = line.split(maxsplit=4)
    *chunk2, rest = while_not_alpha(rest.split())
    rest = list(rest)
    chunk3 = rest[:2]
    chunk4 = rest[2:]
    return chunk1, chunk2, chunk3, chunk4

# See below for definition of `txt`
chunk1, chunk2, chunk3, chunk4 = map(list, zip(*map(parse, txt.splitlines())))
```

We can see that `chunk2` looks like

```
chunk2[:4]

[['30', '16'],
 ['8', '6'],
 ['14', '15'],
 ['14', '15']]
```

And `chunk3`

```
chunk3[:4]

[['OC', '1.355049'],
 ['CC', '1.494281'],
 ['NC', '1.421282'],
 ['NC', '1.421282']]
```

We could have take this a step further to make data frames

```
chunk1, chunk2, chunk3, chunk4 = map(
    pd.DataFrame, map(list, zip(*map(parse, txt.splitlines()))))

chunk2.head()

     0   1     2     3
0   30  16  None  None
1    8   6  None  None
2   14  15  None  None
3   14  15  None  None
4    8   6  None  None
5   30  31  None  None
6   13  11  None  None
7    1   3     7  None
8    3   1     4  None
9    7   3     1  None
10  21  14    15  None
11  24   5     2  None
12  25   2     6  None
13  24   5     2  None
14  25   2     6  None
15  26  19    18  None
16  31  30    16    19
17   8   2     3     6
18   9   3    12     7
```

Or further still:

```
df = pd.concat(
    map(pd.DataFrame, map(list, zip(*map(parse, txt.splitlines())))),
    axis=1, keys=[f'chunk{i}' for i in range(1, 5)]
)

df

   chunk1                  chunk2                 chunk3           chunk4                                          
        0   1      2     3      0   1     2     3      0         1      0   1      2     3      4     5     6     7
0       s  27   1.00  STRE     30  16  None  None     OC  1.355049  f1291  50   None  None   None  None  None  None
1       s  28  -1.00  STRE      8   6  None  None     CC  1.494281  f1340  12  f1271    17   None  None  None  None
2       s  29  -1.00  STRE     14  15  None  None     NC  1.421282  f1358  49   None  None   None  None  None  None
3       s  30   1.00  STRE     14  15  None  None     NC  1.421282  f1337  10  f1290    33   None  None  None  None
4       s  31   1.00  STRE      8   6  None  None     CC  1.494281  f1171  15   f323    11   None  None  None  None
5       s  32   1.00  STRE     30  31  None  None     OC  1.419982  f1082  51  f1077    24   None  None  None  None
6       s  33   1.00  STRE     13  11  None  None    ClC  1.740581   f842  15   f323    19   None  None  None  None
7       s  34  -1.00  BEND      1   3     7  None    CCC    119.62  f1037  26   f485    10   None  None  None  None
8       s  35  -1.00  BEND      3   1     4  None    CCC    119.74  f1124  29   None  None   None  None  None  None
9       s  36   1.00  BEND      7   3     1  None    CCC    119.62   f733  25   f288    13   None  None  None  None
10      s  37   1.00  BEND     21  14    15  None    HNC    116.16  f1578  40  f1560    20   None  None  None  None
11      s  38   1.00  BEND     24   5     2  None    HCC    119.73  f1186  67   None  None   None  None  None  None
12      s  39   1.00  BEND     25   2     6  None    HCC    118.80  f1536  53  f1082    10  f1077    17  None  None
13      s  40  -1.00  BEND     24   5     2  None    HCC    119.73  f1508  44  f1171    14  f1124    13  None  None
14      s  41   1.00  BEND     25   2     6  None    HCC    118.80  f1669  14  f1271    32  f1124    15  None  None
15      s  42  -1.00  BEND     26  19    18  None    HCC    119.04  f1578  10  f1560    37  f1291    11  None  None
16      s  89   1.00  TORS     31  30    16    19   COCC      0.24   f161  14   f104    46    f87    19   f43    10
17      s  90   1.00   OUT      8   2     3     6   CCCC      1.09   f466  36   f125    22   None  None  None  None
18      s  91   1.00   OUT      9   3    12     7   OCCC      0.34   f829  27   f752    33   None  None  None  None
```

---

**Setup**

```
txt = """\
s 27    1.00   STRE   30   16   OC    1.355049  f1291 50
s 28   -1.00   STRE    8    6   CC    1.494281  f1340 12  f1271 17
s 29   -1.00   STRE   14   15   NC    1.421282  f1358 49
s 30    1.00   STRE   14   15   NC    1.421282  f1337 10  f1290 33
s 31    1.00   STRE    8    6   CC    1.494281  f1171 15  f323 11
s 32    1.00   STRE   30   31   OC    1.419982  f1082 51  f1077 24
s 33    1.00   STRE   13   11   ClC    1.740581  f842 15  f323 19
s 34   -1.00   BEND    1    3    7   CCC   119.62  f1037 26  f485 10
s 35   -1.00   BEND    3    1    4   CCC   119.74  f1124 29
s 36    1.00   BEND    7    3    1   CCC   119.62  f733 25  f288 13
s 37    1.00   BEND   21   14   15   HNC   116.16  f1578 40  f1560 20
s 38    1.00   BEND   24    5    2   HCC   119.73  f1186 67
s 39    1.00   BEND   25    2    6   HCC   118.80  f1536 53  f1082 10  f1077 17
s 40   -1.00   BEND   24    5    2   HCC   119.73  f1508 44  f1171 14  f1124 13
s 41    1.00   BEND   25    2    6   HCC   118.80  f1669 14  f1271 32  f1124 15
s 42   -1.00   BEND   26   19   18   HCC   119.04  f1578 10  f1560 37  f1291 11
s 89    1.00   TORS   31   30   16   19   COCC     0.24  f161 14  f104 46  f87 19  f43 10
s 90    1.00   OUT     8    2    3    6   CCCC     1.09  f466 36  f125 22
s 91    1.00   OUT     9    3   12    7   OCCC     0.34  f829 27  f752 33"""
```

Comment: I'm baffled about how elegant this solution is. Thank you @piRSquared.

Comment: @HenriqueJunior that is kind of you to say. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this problem. You can do something like this:

```
text = """s 27    1.00   STRE   30   16   OC    1.355049  f1291 50
s 34   -1.00   BEND    1    3    7   CCC   119.62  f1037 26  f485 10
s 89    1.00   TORS   31   30   16   19   COCC     0.24  f161 14  f104 46  f87 19  f43 10
s 91    1.00   OUT     9    3   12    7   OCCC     0.34  f829 27  f752 33"""

my_file = StringIO(text)

chunks = []
for line in my_file:
    my_data = line.split()
    chunk1 = my_data[:4]
    chunk2 = my_data[4:6]
    for i in range(6, 8):
        if my_data[i].isdigit():
            chunk2.append(my_data[i])
        else:
            break
    chunk3_start = len(chunk1) + len(chunk2)
    chunk3 = my_data[chunk3_start:chunk3_start+2]
    chunk4 = my_data[chunk3_start+2:]
    chunks.append({1: chunk1, 2: chunk2, 3: chunk3, 4: chunk4})
```

Which produces the following output:

```
[{1: ['s', '27', '1.00', 'STRE'],
  2: ['30', '16'],
  3: ['OC', '1.355049'],
  4: ['f1291', '50']},
 {1: ['s', '34', '-1.00', 'BEND'],
  2: ['1', '3', '7'],
  3: ['CCC', '119.62'],
  4: ['f1037', '26', 'f485', '10']},
 {1: ['s', '89', '1.00', 'TORS'],
  2: ['31', '30', '16', '19'],
  3: ['COCC', '0.24'],
  4: ['f161', '14', 'f104', '46', 'f87', '19', 'f43', '10']},
 {1: ['s', '91', '1.00', 'OUT'],
  2: ['9', '3', '12', '7'],
  3: ['OCCC', '0.34'],
  4: ['f829', '27', 'f752', '33']}]
```

Basically you keep adding elements to chunk2 until you encounter something that isn't a number. Use the lengths of chunk1 and chunk2 to get the rest of the chunks.

Comment: Thank you, @pault, it is a very elegant approach here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my variant:

```
def simple_parsing(string):
    from re import split
    parts = split('\s+',string)
    result = [];i=4
    while not parts[i].isalpha():
        result.append(parts[i])
        i+=1
    return([parts[0:4],result,parts[i:i+2],parts[i+2:]])
```

For example, took one string of yours, here's a result:

```
simple_parsing('s 91    1.00   OUT     9    3   12    7   OCCC     0.34  f829 27  f752 33')
[['s', '91', '1.00', 'OUT'], ['9', '3', '12', '7'], ['OCCC', '0.34'], ['f829', '27', 'f752', '33']]
```

Comment: Thanks, Константин Ким, for your suggestion.